# What is the correct way to select nested information from a JSON file in Oracle 12.1.0.2?

Tags: json, oracle, nested

I try to get information from a JSON file, described in the following select statement. This works in Oracle 19 and also on Oracle 12.2.0.1

```
with xmldata as (
  select '{
  "metaData": {
    "validForClearingDay": "2022-11-16",
    "createdStamp": "2022-11-15T16:30:17.329433+01:00"
  },
  "entries": [
    {
      "group": "01",
      "iid": 100,
      "branchId": "0000",
      "sicIid": "001008"
    },
    {
      "group": "01",
      "iid": 110,
      "branchId": "0000",
      "sicIid": "001100"
    }
  ]
}' data from dual)
select y.* from xmldata x,
  JSON_TABLE(x.data,
          '$' COLUMNS(
            validForClearingDay VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.metaData.validForClearingDay',
            NESTED PATH '$.entries[*]'
            COLUMNS (
              "group" VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.group',
              iid NUMBER(10) PATH '$.iid',
              branchId VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.branchId',
              sicIid VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.sicIid'
      ))) y
```

In Oracle 12.1.0.2 I get an error ORA-00936: missing expression Anybody has a clue how the correct syntax in that version has to be?

Comment: NESTED PATH is supposed to work on 12.1, may be a bug with "group" ? try replacing by grp without quotes.

Comment: Great analysis, it really was the "group* column, that seems to be the problem in that Oracle version.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NESTED PATH is supposed to work on 12.1, try replacing by grp without quotes

Answer (score 0):

As p3consulting found out, in Oracle 12.1.0.2 it seems to be a problem to use a reserved word as a column name, even if you put it in quotes.